# Python - TypeError: string indices mustr be integers

Tags: python

I've tried looking at other solutions for this issue, but none of them work or make sense to me.

relevant code:

```
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
options = ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3", "option 4"]
choices = alphabet[0:len(options)]

for i in options:
    print(choices[i], options[i])
```

**Output:
print(choices[i], options[i])
TypeError: string indices must be integers**

I'm looking to get the following output:

`a option 1`

`b option 2`

`c option 3`

`d option 4`

Anyone know what I'm screwing up here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

The issue is, that you're iterating over the elements of `options` which are strings (option1, ...). You have to iterate over the length of your list.

```py
for i in range(len(options)):
    print(choices[i], options[i])
```

Answer (score 2):

You're iterating through the items of the list, not an index.

You can try this:

```
for i, element in enumerate(options):
    print(choices[i], element)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to slice the alphabet, you can just [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) those iterables. It will only zip so many entries how many are in the smaller iterable.

```py
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
options = ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3", "option 4"]

for (letter, opt) in zip(alphabet, options):
    print(letter, opt)
```

**Note**: that approach will work only for options iterables being smaller or equal to 26 entries. If you had more choices, you could use [`itertools.cycle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle), but then you would have multiple options with the same letter, so just adding more unique characters to `alphabet` or changing it to numbers, could solve that problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```py
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
options = ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3", "option 4"]

for i in range(len(options)):
    print(alphabet[i] + " " + options[i])
```

it prints

> a option 1
>
> b option 2
>
> c option 3
>
> d option 4